# IntelliJ settings for Gradle and TestNG

Tags: java, gradle, testng, intellij-14

I started creating a set of tests with Selenium and TestNG (Java base language) in IntelliJ IDEA. I was able to compile and run within IntelliJ, but when I added a Gradle file (shown below) I'm getting some compile path errors.

Gradle:

```
    apply plugin: 'java'


dependencies {
    
    testCompile(group: 'org.uncommons', name: 'reportng', version: '1.1.4') {
        exclude(module: 'testng')
    }

    testCompile group: 'com.google.inject', name: 'guice', version: '3.0'
    compile group: 'xml-apis', name: 'xml-apis', version:'1.4.01'

}

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'xml-apis:xml-apis:1.4.01'
    }
}

task testfeature1(type: Test) {
    ignoreFailures = true
    useTestNG() {
        suites 'Resources/Dashboards/feature1_testng.xml'
        useDefaultListeners = false
        listeners << 'org.uncommons.reportng.HTMLReporter'
        listeners << 'org.uncommons.reportng.JUnitXMLReporter'
    }
}
```

Terminal Output:

```
13:51:08.287 [DEBUG] 

[org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter] Starting to execute task ':testfeature1'
13:51:08.301 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DirectoryFileTree] file or directory '/Users/******/Workspace/TestNG_Automation/build/classes/test', not found
13:51:08.301 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter] Skipping task ':testfeature1' as it has no source files.
```

I'm guessing IntelliJ compiles things to the out folder, as I see that now, but no *build* folder.

How do I change this to make Gradle and IntelliJ work the same way?

Comment: Do you have the intellij plugin in your build.gradle?

Comment: No not that I know of anyways

Comment: it is also complaining you don't have source for test, where are your test classes?

Answer (score 0):

Let me cite another example project I am working on:
https://github.com/virenv/ParallelReporter

At the top of my build.gradle, it is configured like so:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
```

Then setup your project with this command:

```
gradle clean idea
```

If you are getting test output to **/out**, then you are probably running the tests as TestNG, not from the Gradle executor.   If you are doing it right, Gradle will generate a `/build` folder and you can control where your test report is generated with something like this:

```
test {
    reports.html.destination = file("$buildDir/reports/gradle")
    ....
```

One advantage of running the tests as "pure TestNG" rather than using the Gradle executor, is that IntelliJ-IDEA will display to you more information about the individual test successes.   When running with Gradle, IntelliJ-IDEA is not smart enough to show you that info and so you need to rely on your test report.